# Convert two numbers to date in ansi sql

Tags: sql, date

I have two different colunmns:

```
month   year
 6      2014
 7      2014
 8      2014
```

How can I convert this two columns into this?

```
01/06/2014  format: dd/mm/yyyy
```

Is this possible in ansi?

Answer (score 0):

In mysql you can:
`CONCAT (day,'/',month,'/',year)`

|| is the ANSI string concatenation operator (unfortunately, not every database chooses to support the standard). Many databases support a CONCAT function.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
  CONVERT(datetime, (CONCAT('01', '/', t.month, '/', t.year)))
FROM yourtablename t;
```